# Incorrect auto convert to table

Tags: org-mode

windows 10, emacs 26.1

Suppose in my.org I has text:

```
OwnerKey    OrganizationName    GUID

1111350    My TV    aaaaa561-4194-4441-9FA5-4D712B2659EE
3333363    My TV    Abbbbb61-4cccccc41-9ddddddd12B2659EE
4444445    My TV    A3B8F561-4194-4441-9eeeeeeeeeee659EE
5555579    UF-energ electr pers    1111CFD2-Bf444ffff-A985-CB060075D9F3
6666631    Ingineric SRL  36A92222233A2-4A91-9826-7DD4F444442D
```

I need to auto convert them to table.

1. select whole text
2. in menu tbl->Convert region

Result:

```
| OwnerKey | OrganizationName | GUID   |                                      |                                      |
|          |                  |        |                                      |                                      |
|  1111350 | My               | TV     | aaaaa561-4194-4441-9FA5-4D712B2659EE |                                      |
|  3333363 | My               | TV     | Abbbbb61-4cccccc41-9ddddddd12B2659EE |                                      |
|  4444445 | My               | TV     | A3B8F561-4194-4441-9eeeeeeeeeee659EE |                                      |
|  5555579 | UF-energ         | electr | pers                                 | 1111CFD2-Bf444ffff-A985-CB060075D9F3 |
|  6666631 | Ingineric        | SRL    | 36A92222233A2-4A91-9826-7DD4F444442D |                                      |
```

But it not correct. It must smt like this:

```
| OwnerKey | OrganizationName     | GUID                                 |
|----------+----------------------+--------------------------------------|
|  1111350 | My TV                | aaaaa561-4194-4441-9FA5-4D712B2659EE |
|  3333363 | My TV                | Abbbbb61-4cccccc41-9ddddddd12B2659EE |
|  4444445 | My TV                | A3B8F561-4194-4441-9eeeeeeeeeee659EE |
|  5555579 | UF-energ electr pers | 1111CFD2-Bf444ffff-A985-CB060075D9F3 |
|  6666631 | Ingineric SRL        | 36A92222233A2-4A91-9826-7DD4F444442D |
```

I suppose that is because in text has spaces. E.g in "**My TV**".

But how I can fix this?

Comment: Are the fields separated by TAB? In this case, C-u C-u before C-c | will use TAB as separator. Check documentation for `org-table-convert-region`.

Comment: Or use C-u 2 as prefix to separate on 2 or more spaces or TAB.

Comment: You can use `M-x whitespace-mode` to see what whitespace characters separate the table columns.

Comment: @Juancho Fields not separate by TAB. It's separate by spaces.

Answer (score 1):

You can control de behavior of `org-table-convert-region` by giving a numeric prefix before calling. I've quoted part of the documentation below.

Normally, this function works in automatic mode (`nil`). You can choose to use comma, TAB or regexp by prefixing with 1, 2 or 3 <kbd>C-u</kbd>s.

Or, if you prefix with a number (e.g. <kbd>C-2</kbd> or <kbd>C-u 2</kbd>), it uses those many spaces for separating columns.

In your example, with an argument of 2, it works perfectly since all columns are separated by at least 2 spaces.

> (org-table-convert-region BEG0 END0 &optional SEPARATOR)
>
> ...
>
> SEPARATOR specifies the field separator in the lines.  It can have the
>   following values:
>
> (4)     Use the comma as a field separator
>
> (16)    Use a TAB as field
>   separator
>
> (64)    Prompt for a regular expression as field separator
>
> integer  When a number, use that many spaces, or a TAB, as field
>   separator
>
> regexp   When a regular expression, use it to match the
>   separator
>
> nil      When nil, the command tries to be smart and figure
>   out the
>            separator in the following way:
>            - when each line contains a TAB, assume TAB-separated material
>            - when each line contains a comma, assume CSV material
>            - else, assume one or more SPACE characters as separator.